# Getting error on pywinos for executing command

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, package, azure-pipeline-python-script-task

Using python pywinos package, while using below code getting error

```
from pywinos import WinOSClient
tool = WinOSClient( logger_enabled=False)
response = tool.run_cmd(command='whoami')
```

Error:

```
     File "C:\Workspace\GOVScript\envgovscript\lib\site-packages\winrm\__init__.py", line 33, 
     in __init__
           match = re.match(
           File "C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\re.py", line 191, in match
     return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
     TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

And:

```
tool = WinOSClient(host='127.0.0.1', logger_enabled=False)
response = tool.run_cmd(command='whoami')
```

Error:

```
    self.transport = Transport(
  File "C:\Workspace\GOVScript\envgovscript\lib\site-packages\winrm\transport.py", line 154, in __init__       
    raise InvalidCredentialsError("auth method %s requires a username" % self.auth_method)
winrm.exceptions.InvalidCredentialsError: auth method plaintext requires a username
```